# Facebook Debugger unable to test localhost

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, localhost

I am building a Facebook app using Django. So, for development, I connected the app to `localhost`. My app is loading on canvas and working fine but the Facebook [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) is unable to test it correctly when I give localhost address as input.

These are the requests I tried in [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

```
http://localhost
https://localhost/
http://127.0.0.1/
localhost

etc
```

Almost for all possible combinations.. It showed me

```
Error Parsing URL:  Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.
```

When I deployed the same code on heroku and tried.. It was working!

So,

1. Can't I debug the project on localhost? What's the point in working on it then??
2. If I can work, how should I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can't I debug the project on localhost? What's the point in working on it then??

You can debug your code etc. on localhost – but *of course* you can’t have Facebook’s debug tool reach a site on *your* localhost, because Facebook (and everyone else on the web) does have no idea what machine *your* localhost actually is. (Absolute bascis, dude!)

> If I can work, how should I fix it?

You have to make your web server accessible from the “outside”, over the internet.

Set up your test server so that it accepts requests from outside IPs, and get a DynDNS address (basically something that can be resolved by third parties like Facebook over the DNS).

Comment: I am aware of the fact that localhost wouldn't work on other computers but somehow I thought that facebook would connect it by recognizing my IP.. as my app is still in sandbox

Answer (score -3):

You can access Facebook apps locally but you need to fake the domain of your local computer. You can do this by adding

```
127.0.0.1 mysite.test.example.com
```

to `/etc/hosts`. You should update `mysite.test.example.com` to your domain. Your Facebook app needs to be configured for that domain. You can then use the Facebook app locally and debug your project.

The alternative is to setup up a web server and use its domain for testing purposes (but this is not ideal because you'll need to commit and build the code before you can see your changes).

Comment: Your _local_ hosts file is not gonna bother the Facebook debug tool much.

Comment: Not the Facebook debugger but it will give the correct referer URL which allows you to develop with Facebook apps locally.